# how to shorten or optimize JOIN query in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I got following query, in which I am joining 4 times. But it takes lot of time to return the result. 
Is there any way to optimize this query ?

```
    SELECT T1.wbd_date as WBD_DATE,  to_char(T1.wbd_block_no, 'fm00') as BLOCK_NO, T2.wbd_value as AmbHum, T3.wbd_value as AmbTemp,
T4.wbd_value as SWT, T5.wbd_value as Expval
FROM (
SELECT wbd_attribute_id, wbd_date, wbd_block_no, wbd_value 
FROM wb_block_data ) T1 
JOIN wb_block_data T2 on T1.wbd_date = T2.wbd_date AND T1.wbd_block_no = T2.wbd_block_no and T2.wbd_attribute_id = 152112 and to_char(T2.wbd_date,'MM YYYY')='07 2019'
JOIN wb_block_data T3 on T1.wbd_date = T3.wbd_date AND T1.wbd_block_no = T3.wbd_block_no and T3.wbd_attribute_id = 152116 and to_char(T3.wbd_date,'MM YYYY')='07 2019'
JOIN wb_block_data T4 on T1.wbd_date = T4.wbd_date AND T1.wbd_block_no = T4.wbd_block_no and T4.wbd_attribute_id = 152120 and to_char(T4.wbd_date,'MM YYYY')='07 2019'
JOIN wb_block_data T5 on T1.wbd_date = T5.wbd_date AND T1.wbd_block_no = T5.wbd_block_no and T5.wbd_attribute_id = 150661 and to_char(T5.wbd_date,'MM YYYY')='07 2019'
```

Comment: It might help if T2, ..., T5 had an index on (wbd_date, wbd_block_no, wbd_attribute_id) - this should enable efficient hash joins.

Comment: @HenningKoehler Maybe not, as the `wbd_date` column appears inside a function.

Comment: Since all the data has taken from July 2019, I have included where condition inside T1 and now this query executes faster

Comment: What data type is `wbd_value`?

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially doing a pivot, doing that using conditional aggregation might be faster:

```
select wbd_attribute_id, block_no, wbd_date,
       max(wbd_value) filter (where wbd_attribute_id = 152112) as AmbHum,
       max(wbd_value) filter (where wbd_attribute_id = 152116) as AmbTemp,
       max(wbd_value) filter (where wbd_attribute_id = 152120) as swt,
       max(wbd_value) filter (where wbd_attribute_id = 152120) as Expval
from (
  SELECT wbd_attribute_id, wbd_date, to_char(wbd_block_no, 'fm00') as block_no, wbd_value 
  FROM wb_block_data 
  where wbd_attribute_id in (152112, 152116, 152120, 150661)
    and wbd_date >= DATE '2019-07-01' 
    and wbd_date < DATE '2019-08-01'
) t
group by wbd_attribute_id, wbd_date, block_no
```

You want an index on `(wbd_attribute_id, wbd_date)` for that.

Answer (score 0):

An index such as the following might work:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON wb_block_data (wbd_date, wbd_block_no, wbd_attribute_id);
```

However, we would also need to make the join conditions sargable:

```
SELECT T1.wbd_date as WBD_DATE, to_char(T1.wbd_block_no, 'fm00') as BLOCK_NO, T2.wbd_value as AmbHum, T3.wbd_value as AmbTemp, T4.wbd_value as SWT, T5.wbd_value as Expval
FROM
(
    SELECT wbd_attribute_id, wbd_date, wbd_block_no, wbd_value 
    FROM wb_block_data
) T1 
JOIN wb_block_data T2 on T1.wbd_date = T2.wbd_date AND T1.wbd_block_no = T2.wbd_block_no and T2.wbd_attribute_id = 152112 and T2.wbd_date >= '2019-07-01' and T2.wbd_date < '2019-08-01'
JOIN wb_block_data T3 on T1.wbd_date = T3.wbd_date AND T1.wbd_block_no = T3.wbd_block_no and T3.wbd_attribute_id = 152116 and T3.wbd_date >= '2019-07-01' and T3.wbd_date < '2019-08-01'
JOIN wb_block_data T4 on T1.wbd_date = T4.wbd_date AND T1.wbd_block_no = T4.wbd_block_no and T4.wbd_attribute_id = 152120 and T4.wbd_date >= '2019-07-01' and T4.wbd_date < '2019-08-01'
JOIN wb_block_data T5 on T1.wbd_date = T5.wbd_date AND T1.wbd_block_no = T5.wbd_block_no and T5.wbd_attribute_id = 150661 and T5.wbd_date >= '2019-07-01' and T5.wbd_date < '2019-08-01';
```

The only change I made to your query was to express the date requirement as a range, without using `to_char`:

```
wbd_date >= '2019-07-01' and wbd_date < '2019-08-01'
```

This is *sargable*, meaning that Postgres might able to use an index on the `wbd_date` column to satisfy the July, 2019 date range.

Answer (score 0):

I changed query to this and with this I am getting desired result quickly

```
SELECT T1.wbd_date as WBD_DATE,  to_char(T1.wbd_block_no, 'fm00') as BLOCK_NO, T2.wbd_value as AmbHum, T3.wbd_value as AmbTemp,
T4.wbd_value as SWT, T5.wbd_value as Expval
FROM (
SELECT wbd_attribute_id, wbd_date, wbd_block_no, wbd_value 
FROM wb_block_data where to_char(wbd_date,'MM YYYY')='07 2019') T1 
JOIN wb_block_data T2 on T1.wbd_date = T2.wbd_date AND T1.wbd_block_no = T2.wbd_block_no and T2.wbd_attribute_id = 152112 
JOIN wb_block_data T3 on T1.wbd_date = T3.wbd_date AND T1.wbd_block_no = T3.wbd_block_no and T3.wbd_attribute_id = 152116 
JOIN wb_block_data T4 on T1.wbd_date = T4.wbd_date AND T1.wbd_block_no = T4.wbd_block_no and T4.wbd_attribute_id = 152120 
JOIN wb_block_data T5 on T1.wbd_date = T5.wbd_date AND T1.wbd_block_no = T5.wbd_block_no and T5.wbd_attribute_id = 150661
```